# Photoshop CS5 Polygon Tool smooth corners "too smooth"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I'm trying to create an 8-sided shape with the polygon tool. This is not a problem, but if I want smooth corners for my shape and I check the option "smooth corners" its too smooth - its basical a circle.

Is there an "smoothness" option which I have to adjust?

Comment: I found a workaround for now: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2769/create-a-triangle-with-rounded-corners

Comment: As Vickash noted, you are much better off using Illustrator to do this if you have it. If you just need Illustrator for a portion of your image, you can copy whatever you create in from Illustrator and paste it into Photoshop as a smart object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple workaround.

1) Create your polygon

2) Select it, and create a layer mask

3) Select the layer mask and smooth it.

4) Adjust the layer mask to include the smooth.

This way you maintain the actual polygon, you just mask the corners to make it seem rounded. This way is easily adjustable by further smoothing the mask or erasing the mask.

My  result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why Photoshop doesn't let you adjust the radius when using that smooth option, but if you have Illustrator, you can get what you need by first creating the shape in Illustrator, then applying Effect > Stylize > Round Corners with an appropriate setting.

This is a vector effect that isn't available inside Photoshop. Once you've rounded the corners on the shape in Illustrator, you can select it, copy it, and paste it into Photoshop as a path or shape layer to work on further.

Comment: I don't really understand it either, that is why I thought there might be a hidden option somewhere. Sadly I don't have Illustrator.

Comment: You can try zachzum's workaround instead then. Draw the polygon as a path instead of a shape layer first. Then convert it to a selection. At this point you do what zachzum said. Then you can convert the selection back to a path which you can use for the shape layer's clipping mask. This won't necessarily give as clean a result, but it'd work.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a radius option just by the smooth corners option.

Comment: Hmm, Vickash's answer implies this option doesn't exist: "Photoshop doesn't let you adjust the radius when using that smooth option" - is this a new feature in a later version perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

When yo go to [Top Menu -> Select -> Modify -> Smooth] a window pops up asking you for your radius. If you are dealing with a very small image you may need to increase your image resolution in order to get finder smoothing.

Comment: While this may be a workaround if he is willing to use a selection instead, this doesn't really answer the OP's question. He's asking about the polygon tool, which is path-based, not alpha-based.

Comment: Suggesting other ways to do the same thing can be an answer to a question.

Comment: Of course, and that's why Johannes's answer is the accepted one. The thing is, your suggestion is missing steps which are required for this to make sense as an answer to the question, which is why I made the comment. Your suggestion required the OP to convert his polygon into a selection first—without doing this, the steps you describe would be impossible. Just so you know, I never down-voted your answer, I only made the comment.

Comment: You are right I should have explained it better.