# Triangle for a popover (Photoshop)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I am currently making a popover in Photoshop. I managed to do the main part using the `rounded rectangular tool` but not the triangle part:

[image: popover]

Is there a recommend way in Photoshop to do this triangle ?

**EDIT**

I have seen this [post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2769/create-a-triangle-with-rounded-corners) which is the closest to what i want but :

1. I don't want round corner
2. I want a stroke on the triangle but not on the basis

Comment: Got reference? Scott's answer is a good one... but if you're after something different, visual reference would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the pen tool to add 3 anchors to the rounded rectangle path. Then use the Direct Selection Tool (the white arrow) to pull out the middle anchor.

[image: traingle]